# Storyboard doesn't appear to be loading properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a storyboard in a project I am working on, but recently I have noticed that I am having issues. Out of nowhere, my code is now telling me I need to register a class for a cell identifier

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier rootCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

(I have the cell prototype in the storyboard, so I don't believe I need to.) if I perform

`[tableView registerClass:<my class> forCellReuseIdentifier:<identifer>];`

it will get beyond that, but then it hangs up when I

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:<my ID> sender:self];`

and tells me that it cannot find the segue. I was able to confirm the segue is setup with the proper Identifier in the storyboard.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

I did a rename on the storyboard a while back, but I updated info.plist and I'm pretty sure it still worked after that.

If I re-create the storyboard in another project, it works fine, but if I re-create the storyboard in this project, it fails.

EDIT: I do have the class set correctly in IB
also this is a manual segue.

EDIT: Added exact error wording.

Comment: How does the exact (initial) error look like?

Comment: I added the exact error message.

Comment: Is there a cell with the identifier `rootCell` in your Storyboard?

Comment: yes I have confirmed it multiple times. http://cl.ly/image/120w3F0k1R2p

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen.

Had to add `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"WhateverCellID"];` in my viewDidLoad

I was using a regular viewController, realized my mistake, and switched to a tableViewController and started getting the same error.

Alternatively use 'UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`
Without the indexPath option this is a different call, which doesn't require registration and may suit your needs.

Comment: That doesn't work. Even if I fix the dequeue, it still crashes when I try to segue.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the storyboard from your iPhone/iPad/Simulator or wherever you're debugging it, and then clean in Xcode, then build & run, do you see different results? The reason I ask is that each time you build in Xcode, you get a union of everything your project has ever contained. So if you renamed the storyboard, and haven't done a full clean, you likely have both storyboards in your built product.